# Does MvvmCross have a standard converter, which returns null on an empty numeric field?

Tags: mvvmcross

A **Single?** property is bound to a numberDecimal EditText. MvvmCross updates the property value for every nonempty EditText input. But it does not update the property when the EditText is empty, while i need to have **null** value of the property for an empty input.

I've written a stupid solution to this problem using a custom converter

```
public class PriceValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<Single?, String>
{
    protected override float? ConvertBack(string sourceValue, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {                      
        Single targetValue;
        if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceValue) && 
            Single.TryParse(sourceValue, out targetValue))
            return targetValue;

        return null;
    }

    protected override string Convert(float? value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

which can be set to an EditText using local:MvxBind="Text Price,Converter=Price".
But it is not an elegant way.

Edit:

The code for the property of the view-model is following:

```
    public Single? Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Price);
        }
    }

    private Single? _price;
```

Setter of the property as well as RaisePropertyChanged are called only when bounded EditText has some content (nonempty). So when i remove all digits from EditText, the associated property is equal to the last nonempty value, while i need **Price=null** for the empty input.

If I try to set a breakpoint when calling RaisePropertyChanged, it is called only when EditText is nonempty and not called when it is empty.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the code for the property of the view-model?

Did you make sure you are actually calling RaisePropertyChanged on the property?

If you try to set a breakpoint when calling RaisePropertyChanged, is it working?

Comment: Dear Andrei, I have edited my question according to your post.

Comment: I see what you mean. I haven't checked it. If you try to change to string instead of Single? does the property get updated with an empty or null string when the text is cleared from EditText?

Comment: Yes, it does. When i use a string property in the view-model, it tracks any, even blank, content of EditText. But holding a decimal value in the string type considered a bad style.